# Viewstate invalid length error

Tags: .net, asp.net, viewstate

I've been trying to get to the bottom of the old Invalid length for a Base-64 char array and Invalid character in a Base-64 string.

It's a large ViewState, as I'm storing a big chunk of data in there that I don't want the user requesting from the database every three seconds.  Because it was so large (4 meg in some cases), I'm compressing it with Gzip, and overriding LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() and SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(ByVal pageViewState As Object) and creating a custom viewstate.

Problem is, every now and then the above error is occurring. I'm trying to get to the bottom of this, and so store in Session the initial View state length when calling SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium, and compare it with the new viewstate length in LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium.  What I've noticed is that the Viewstate length has been severely cut, and I'm wondering what could be causing this.

I have also noticed + characters appearing in the second string (I was taking the rightmost 10 of each to see if anything was being added initially).  It's also definitely happening more for one user than others, which either indicates issues with the data he deals with, or with his physical connection to the system (speed, software, browser etc).

Does anyone have any ideas?  We also have a number of blades servicing the users, so I was wondering if it might be as a user to pushed from one to the other, but I need to check this.

I had also heard that it could be to do with rendering, but I thought viewstate was loaded before render?

Comment: are you sure this data you store in there has to be available at page render? From your description I guess Cache would also be ok if you set and get this data from code behind and is not needed to render the page layout for the controls. ViewState should be small and only related to the page. Bigger piece of data cab be stored in Session if per user or Cache if per application.

Comment: @DavidePiras I was thinking exactly the same thing. I think using the cache will be faster and cleaner. And it has the great side-effect of getting around your ViewState issue.

Comment: yes but keep in mind that Cache is application wide, if this data you are storing is different for every user connected, use Session.

Comment: Cache is definitely an option, but this is per user, and I'm wanting to avoid the complications and calculations that may arise from making  that change.  The page is stable and performing well at the moment, having been extremely troublesome in the past.  The above error is only occurring about once every 1000-1500 postbacks or so.

Comment: It's probably happening because the ViewState hasn't finished downloading before the page is posted back again. You can't lug around a 5MB ViewState without side-effects.

Comment: I Overrode Page Render temporarily to see when it was called, and it was always after SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium.  Since  LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium comes before this, and performs the decompression, I would expect (from what I've read - I may be wrong) the viewstate has been downloaded/finished with by the rendering stage.  This had been one of my initial thoughts, though.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in my comment above you should analyse, understand and decide if that amount of data really needs to be sent back and forth at every page load; if it belongs to the page and is used by some user controls or if it's only used by you in the code behind in some kind of hand made caching mechanism.

I don't repeat all articles you can find online, the alternatives are ViewState for small amount of data only relevant in that page and per request, Session as per user cache and Cache as per application cache.

Read this article for more details: [How to Choose From Viewstate, Session, Application, Cache, and Cookies](http://ahmedsiddiqui.articlesbase.com/programming-articles/how-to-choose-from-viewstate-session-application-cache-and-cookies-443393.html)

Comment: Cache and session still have the issue of having to be stored.  I'd would still rather see if I can get to the bottom of the exception issue first, as, like I say, the page is performing very well apart from this, and wasn't in the past.  Plus, if I was to use session I'd still need to be compressing as well, since the normal size of the dataset is 4MB.

Comment: @user676767: You are so wrong here that it's painful. Nobody, and I mean nobody, will support the idea of storing a 5MB dataset in ViewState. That's just plain nuts.

Comment: > cache and session still have the issue of having to be stored < The overhead of storing a paltry, tiny 4Mb in session state is miniscule compared to the overhead of shipping 5Mb over the wire. Although your application might seem to be humming along with 0% CPU utilisation, that's because your clients are I/O bound, waiting for page loads!

Comment: Sorry, I've perhaps misconstrued how compressing the ViewState works, but I though that only the compressed size counted when posting back up to the server.  It's around 3 -4MB prior to compression.  After compression it's around (from one just calculated) 120KB.  In terms of CPU though, I don't know how costly it is to process this.  However, response is extremely fast on the pages.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be storing large chunks of data in ViewState. That's not what the ViewState was designed for, and it will *kill* the performance of your page.

You should always try limit the number of hits to the database, but not at the expense of everything else. You're putting an enormous amount of stress on the web server by forcing it to post and serve 5MB pages every request.

If the data is user-specific then store it in session. If the data is not user-specific, then it might be a good fit for caching. Whatever the case, do not put it in ViewState. Moving the data to Session should solve the problem.

Comment: I've left another comment above.  I'm compressing the viewstate before posting it back.  It gets reduced to a couple of hundred KB each request.  If I use a Session variables, then these, I think, are stored on the server?  So how costly is it to request this in relation to compression and decompression?

Comment: You still seem to be missing the point. Even after compression, a 5MB DataSet will probably be 3MB, and that's being optimistic. Your ViewState should not be more than 100KB, and even that's pushing it. Default InProc session is stored in memory on the server, and is more appropriate for storing such large objects. It would be ideal if you could store it in Cache, but since the data is user-specific, then session is the best place to store it.

Comment: Compression rate is actually 10X, having checked. However, truncation can occur at 45kb, but again, erratically (1 in 1500 postbacks). The reason I asked the above question is that our 6 blades and one sqlserver are quite strained as it is. It's not just a case of what's 'proper', it's a case of ensuring everything performs well.  There are a lot of concurrent users, so really, if I'm to consider changing to session, I need to be be aware of the alternate costs of both implementations.  I can deal with an erratic exception if it means the speed is better for 99%.

Comment: Having checked the sizes again, the max (after compression) is about 300 kb, but usually 60kb.  In addtion to the above, the primary concern is that there are ten other apps on the same server setup, so having large session objects could potentially be a problem.

Comment: Another addition - I've found that we employ Sqlserver mode for the session state, which I think is the slowest.